# error in changing the background color in ng for loop angular 4

Tags: angular, ionic2

in my ionic app i am trying to generate different color for each list item for that i have written the following function in my comp.ts

```
getRandomColor() {
     var trans = '0.5'; // 50% transparency
     var color = 'rgba(';
     for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
       color += Math.floor(Math.random() * 255) + ',';
      }
     color += trans + ')'; // add the transparency
      return color;
      }
```

and in my html file i am calling it like below

```
     <ion-content>
            <ion-list class="quoteList" *ngIf = "data" no-lines>
              <button ion-item *ngFor="let item of data" [ngStyle]="
                   {'backgroundColor': getRandomColor() }"
                          (click)="quoteSelected(item)">
                  {{ item.name }}
                 </button>  
             </ion-list>
     </ion-content>
```

but i am getting the following error,what i need to change for getting rid of the below error

```
Error: ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'backgroundColor: background-color:rgba(106,186,144,0.5)'. Current value: 'backgroundColor: background-color:rgba(200,98,210,0.5)'.
at viewDebugError (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:10149:32)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What's happening here is that if you do not change the object reference, but only some of its properties, the angular's change detection will not be triggered.

So your changes to background-color are recognized only in the next change detection run, which is not something that you want.

In development mode Angular actually runs two change detection runs to catch  mistakes like this one. And the error message you are seeing is the result of that.

component.html

```
<ion-content>
  <ion-list class="quoteList" *ngIf = "data" no-lines>
    <button ion-item *ngFor="let item of data" [ngStyle]="getColor()" (click)="quoteSelected(item)">
       {{ item.name }}
    </button>  
  </ion-list>
</ion-content>
```

component.ts

```
getColor() {
  const color = this.getRandomColor();

  return {
    'background-color' : color
  }
}


getRandomColor() {
   // calc and return random rgba
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you set colors ahead, that should avoid the message. Something like:

```
  colors=[];
  ...
  for (let i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
      this.colors.push(this.getRandomColor());
    }
  }
```

[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-j9tyx3)